# Node Express 500 Error: Unknown encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am running an Express application on Nodejitsu. It's Node 0.8 and Express 3.4.0. The application works absolutely fine locally, but one of the routes has stopped working and returns the following error when I push to Nodejitsu:

```
Express
500 Error: Unknown encoding
at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:440:13)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:241:33)
at handleCache (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:65:21)
at exports.renderFile    (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:206:14)
at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:510:22)
at View.render (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
at Function.app.render (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:504:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7)
at exports.m2 (/opt/run/snapshot/package/routes/login.js:27:9)
at callbacks (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
```

I have nt changed anything about the route. I added a new route to the sme routing file which works, but should not affect this route). I haven't changes the view template in any way, or done anything I can think of to change the encoding. Given that Nodejitsu just takes my package.json and installs all the same modules, everything about the app should be identical.

I'm not sure how to track down the issue since the Nodejitsu logs are identical to the output error and I can't reproduce locally. I tried commenting out the new route, and it had no effect.

Comment: It's giving you the line numbers where toString is failing to convert a buffer from a read file ?

Comment: Right, I assume this is part of the process of converting the template file to a string. Again, I can't figure out why or where the failure is happening. I'm not sure what the encoding issue is or why it only happens in production.

Comment: It's even harder for us to figure out. Place some breakpoints or console.logs in the code, and try to narrow down where exactly the error is occurring.

Comment: I know where the error is occurring. Essentially it's when the route calls res.render() and tries to render the ejs template. What I don't understand is why the app is complaining about encoding and how I might track the problem down.